# Checking PHP referrer

Tags: php, regex

So, I need to check the referrer to a page using php, and if it is *.example.com, or *.anothersite.com, execute code, but if not, redirect elsewhere.

How would I go about checking if the HTTP_REFERER is equal to those values, with a wildcard character?

Thanks!

EDIT: The url will contain more than one domain, so the regex needs to match the FIRST occurance found.

Comment: Be aware that unless you can control the browsers accessing this script, you can't rely very much on HTTP_REFERRER.  It will often be empty, such as if redirected from an SSL site, or if the user sets browser security settings to prevent sending the HTTP_REFERRER.

Comment: Yeah, I don't need to strongly rely on it, it's an additional verification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Other answers' checks' are good but are not strictly bound to your website. So for example referer with value `http://attacker.com/www.example.com/` will pass almost all the checks. And it is very easy to make such site and just send a cross-domain request.

There is a reliable and secure method to check if referer is ***really*** your domain. Of course referer can be spoofed, but a victim of an attacker site will send correct referer.

The trick is in `^` special character. Here is the magic regex:

```
^https?://(([a-z0-9-]+)\.)*example\.com/
```

`^` - ensures that we are at the start
`https?` - protocol - http or https
`(([a-z0-9-]+)\.)*` - matches subdomains, also of higher levels, if any
`example\.com` - matches main domain
`/` - ensures start of path so domain name cannot continue

Comment: If you wish either http or https it should be `http?` ;)

Comment: @alekwisnia no... question mark means that character before it may occur at max once (So it may be also 0 times). So `https?` matches `http` and `https` and your example matches `htt` and `http`

Comment: Given that referrer can be spoofed or completely omitted, this should be the #1 answer as every little bit helps. (Only thing I'd add is the use of $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] instead of hard coding the domain name.)

Comment: Just came back to this a decade(!) later, the more secure method is definitely the correct answer!

Answer (score 31):

Should do it:

```
$allowed_host = 'example.com';
$host = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST);

if(substr($host, 0 - strlen($allowed_host)) == $allowed_host) {
  // some code
} else {
  // redirection
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (strpos($ref, 'example.com') !== FALSE) {
   redirect to wherever example.com people should go
}
if (strpos($ref, 'example.org') !== FALSE) {
    redirect to wherever example.org people should go
}
```

Of course, this only works if the referer is "nice". For instance, coming from google you could possibly have "example.org" in the search term somewhere, in which case strpos would see it, and redirect, even though you came from google.

Comment: What if the allowed host is `iana.org` and the referer is `www.iana.org.nyud.net`? **(actual domain)**

Comment: Referer checking is rarely reliable, since it's something that's completely under the control of the user.

Comment: What if the attacker's page address is `http:://evil-attacker.org/example.com/...`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (preg_match('/\.example\.(com|org)/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
{
  // execute your code
}
else
{
  header("Location: http://example.com/redirectpage.htm");
  exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match('/(.+?)\.example\.(com|org)/',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])`

This will only match an address that has a subdomain, and it also will not continue looking for anything beyond `subdomain.example.com` or `.org`. i.e. `subdomain.example.com/some-other-stuff`. Do you need to also match either of these?

Correction - this will match `www.example.com` but will not match `example.com`.