# How to get the page from which a user was redirected

Tags: javascript, php

I'm looking for a way i can get the page that redirected to mine.

For example, if a user is on http://facebook.com and he clicks on a link that bring him to my page http://example.com, how do i get the url (http://facebook.com) for which such user came from.

PS: My english is not so good.

Comment: Get the `Referer` header from the request, but be aware that for fairly obvious security reasons you may well not get anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032889/checking-php-referrer

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can use **`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`**

**From PHP MANUAL**: 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php
*The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.*

**HTTP referer WIKI**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer