# Access website Y only after you are redirected from website X

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a slightly strange question and I'm not sure if this could be achieved at all but anyway I'm curious to try.

I have 2 sites that are independent, lets say [www.site1.com](http://www.site1.com) and [www.site2.com](http://www.site2.com).
site2 will be placed in a href in site1. The question is - is it possible site2 to be accessible only after the user is redirected to it from site1 and if the user tries to open site2 directly or thru an a href from another site different then site1 to not be able to access it?

Comment: You can set a cookie on site1 and check it on site2. It should be some cryptographically signed token you can verify so it won't be spoofed, and it should have some lifetime, or a one time use. There is also referrer header but that can be easily faked.

Comment: @RaniSharim cookies are domain specific.

Comment: This is done server-side using the referrer. With PHP for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032889/checking-php-referrer

Comment: @RaniSharim Yes, if you make an AJAX request to site2 to create the cookie that way, then this will work of course. But telling a beginner to "set a cookie on site1" without mentioning it's actually a credentials-enabled ajax request to site 2 might be misleading at best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for:

```
window.document.referrer
// Empty if User is directly loading page.
```

The value is an empty string if the user navigated to the page directly (not through a link, but, for example, by using a bookmark). Because this property returns only a string, it doesn't give you document object model (DOM) access to the referring page.

MDN Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer

Browser Support:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can check for a post parameter that you set from the website 1 redirection (either through a form or plain javascript). And then set a local storage variable to check for when loading site 2.

[Local storage doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

[JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)

But keep in mind this can be **easily bypassed** with enough html/js knowledge.

To ensure that only your website can make post parameter, you could maybe (*not sure about me there*): generate code (used as post parameter) on the go from webserver 1 and send them to webserver 2 at the same time (or a little before) to ensure the code received by the server 2 is really generated at server 1

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the backend server you are using, you can use something called `REFERRER` details that will be there in the `http header` of the request ( for your `www.site2.com` page for example). This `REFERRER` will have the information on who referred the user to this site. You can add a condition something like `if REFERRER is www.site1.com then render the page` .

Here is a link to start with
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer