# Redirect Page If Not Referred

Tags: php, wordpress, function, redirect, refer

Can anybody help with what should be a simple redirect issue in WordPress?

I have a couple of pages that are part of a sign-up process that I want to 'hide' unless accessed as part of that process.

For example, the page '/join/payment-setup/' needs to be inaccessible unless a visitor has come from the '/join/' page - just a simple redirect to the '/join/' page would suffice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking PHP referrer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032889/checking-php-referrer)

Comment: Checking (only) the referer seems like a bad solution. I suggest you check some condition set in the server storage (DB, session, Redis...) and redirect back if the condition is not met (for example if the user has not confirmed something in the "join" page)

Comment: Checking (only) the referer seems like a bad solution, because some browsers allow users to disable referer information for stealth reasons. Your solution will not work for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a WordPress expert, but with a quick run through the documentation, I would probably do it with a mix of using `sessions`, `wp_get_referer()`, and `wp_redirect()`.

1. Start the session at the top of the page

```php
session_start()
```

2. Check the `wp_get_referer` if it matches the `/join/` page. If it does, save some session status for later use. This should be checked on every page to ensure it also gets reset. Notice that with this setup, if the user refreshes the page in the `payment-setup` page, they will lose access. So you would have to add some logic to deal with that.

```php
if (wp_get_referer() === home_url('/join/')) {
    $_SESSION['allowed'] = true;
} 
else {
    $_SESSION['allowed'] = false;
}
```

3. In the `page` you want to control the access, check if a user is allowed to go there, similarly to preventing access before the user signs in. If the user has not come from the right page, re-direct them to the correct page using `wp-redirect` and exit the code.

```php
if (!isset($_SESSION['allowed']) || !$_SESSION['allowed']) {
    wp_redirect(home_url('/join/'));
    exit;
}
```